# Update recyclerview adapter onResume from Different Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

So I have a fragment with recyclerview in it which is a direct child of my first Activity. In my recyclerview rows I have imagebutton. So for my second activity I have a feature where it can change the image of the imagebutton from my first activity's recyclerview. Can somebody help me?

Update:
My application has an addtocard feature. So in the first activity there's individual imagebutton for every row of my recyclerview. When i tap the imagebutton, the image will change and it will be added to the cart. I also have a database for the cart so the ID's of the product get inserted when it is added. If i tap the recyclerview row it will call the second activity and will display the product. So in the second Activity I also have the add to card feature. The problem is when I add the product in the cart inside the second activity i want to update the recyclerview in my first activity to indicate that it was already added.

Comment: Could you please explain your problem in a more accurate way? Also show some of your code.

Comment: What I am doing in the second activity is updating the sqlite database. Its like addtocart feature when in whenever i tap the button in the second activity it will be added to the cart. So then when i go back to the first activity where the list is there will be an indicator that it was added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some kind of shared state where the fragment can read from and the second activity can write into. Since I don't known what you use case is I would suggest that you use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) for the first POC implementation.

In the *onBindView* of the adapter of the fragment you check the preferences for the image to use. It can be a R.whatever.id or a URI pointing to the image. In the second activity you set the key to the image resource depending on your requirements.

Or, this might be a better solution actually, pass the reference to the image in your data source of the adapter. Then whenever you need to update the image write the value in the data source and notify the adapter that there are some changes. If you don't use a content provider and are not observing the data source, then reload the contents in the *onResume* method of the fragment.

But to provide a more accurate answer we need more informations about your use case and the existing code.

Comment: Its an addtocart feature. The flow is when I tap the recyclerview I will view the product in the second activity. So in the second activity there is a button when I can add it to cart. When i add it and after i dismiss the second activity I wan to have an indicator which is my imagebutton to change its imageresource to some icon.

Comment: What is the structure of the data you are passing to the adapter? Is it possible to distinguish from it that an specific item was added to the cart?

Comment: Im using objects to populate my adapter. I have a boolean value that i filter in the adpater to distinguish what image is to load in my imagebutton

Comment: From the other comments I know that you are using a database. Is the boolean value of the objects set from the values read from the db? If not then I would try to implement it so that it. Assuming you have at least the two tables products (fragment) and cart (populated by activity) you'll need to write a query that produces a result set that can be used in the fragment and has an extra column describing the state if the item is already in the shopping cart. With that data you then create the objects, initialize the boolean flag and be done.

Comment: I kinda understand what your pointing out. Yes the boolean value was from the database. I think its better to query inside the adapter so when i notifydatasetchanged()?

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I put a query on my adapter so that it will get refreshed when i call the notifydatasetchanged.

Comment: You can do that, but if there are many items in the adapter it might decrease performance. I would try to change the query that provides the result for the adapter so that it includes this information. That way only the database has to do the heavy lifting, but thats whats its for. Anyway, good luck with the implementation.

Comment: I made a method in my sqlhelperclass that just returns a boolean. I didnt know that notifydatasetchanged will refresh all of the recyclerview. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Use  Callback or Interface. Tigger it when you click and use that interface method to set the Change the Image. Actually I don't Understand Your Question properly. Can you please provide the Code. So i can give proper Answer. What i understand i gave the Answer.

Comment: I tried this however I had problems accessing the button from the second activity.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your model object and list position to second activity.

**FirstActivity.java**

```
private static final int REQUIEST_ITEM_DETAILS = 150;

private void showItemDetails(Item item, int position) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(SecondActivity.EXTRA_ITEM, item);
    intent.putExtra(SecondActivity.EXTRA_POSITION, position);
    context.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUIEST_ITEM_DETAILS);
}
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
private Item item;
private int position;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    item = getIntent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_ITEM);
    position = getIntent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_POSITION, -1);
}

/* 
 * finish your activity with onBackPressed function. so android device's 
 * Back button and your finishing operation will be same function.
 */
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ITEM, item);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_POSITION, position);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

**and in your FirstActivity.java catch onActivityResult**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ITEM_DETAILS) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            int position = data.getIntExtra(SecondActivity.EXTRA_POSITION, -1);
            Item item = data.getParcelableExtra(SecondActivity.EXTRA_ITEM);
            /* put setItem function to your adapter class. it will just replace given item with in your list item */
            adapter.setItem(position, item);
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the sample! I would try this as my future reference. But what will be the difference of this if I just query inside my adapter?

Comment: @OmerKarakose  Nice solution.  Can you please add an example above for the setItem() function in the Adapter?  It is to basically update an existing item?